# Como corrigir um erro JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

Estou utilizando a biblioteca javascript [p5.js](https://p5js.org/download/), e estou tentando acessar arquivos **locais**, no caso atual estou tentando carregar um arquivo json através da função **loadJSON(url)** fornecida pela biblioteca. Porém estou tendo alguns erros nesta tentativa. Já veriquei a formatação do arquivo json e está correta.

 **Obs**: No navegador Mozila Firefox está funcionando corretamente, mas no Google Chrome e Opera estão gerando os mesmos erros dispostos na imagem:

```js
var jsonn1;
function preload(){
  jsonn1 = loadJSON("json1.json");
}

function setup() {
  testeJSON();
}

function draw() {
}

function testeJSON(){
  document.getElementById('teste').innerHTML = jsonn1[0].titulo;
  document.getElementById('teste').setAttribute('href', jsonn1[1].link);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>json test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-viewport, initial-scale=1" />

    <!--CDN Files-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/addons/p5.dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/p5.js"></script>

    <!--Local Files-->
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="sketch.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="json1.json"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="teste" href="">
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: CORS não funciona com o protocolo `file`, já tentou executar seu código com um servidor `http`?

Comment: Não tentei, mas se funcionar em um servidor http, posso ter a certeza que irá funcionar corretamente quando eu hospedar minha página ?

Comment: Ainda não sei, vou fazer uns testes para ver se é isso

Comment: Testei somente sem seu código, me parece ser um problema com a biblioteca

Comment: Eu testei em um servidor local aqui e funcionou corretamente, mas ainda tenho a dúvida, será que irá funcionar depois que eu hospedar minha página? não sei muito sobre back-end

Comment: Depende de como você vai configurar, mas acho que ainda sim vai dar erro, pelo o que vi, a ordem dos imports está errada

Comment: Qual seria a ordem correta?

Comment: Primeiro `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/p5.js"></script>` depois `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/addons/p5.dom.js"></script>`